# Memory address out of bounds

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I'm trying to write a "hello world" program in mips, using QTSpim. The input is:

```
    .data
    str: .asciiz "Hello World" 
    .text
    main:
        lw $a0,str
        li $v0,4
        syscall
        jr $ra
```

When i run this code in QTSpim, it reaches the syscall line and returns an error: "Memory address out of bounds". I've seen tutorials on the internet with this exact code, i don't know what's wrong.
[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3tIg.jpg)

Comment: What is supposed to do `lw $a0,str`? It is not standard syntax, but what is done, at least in mars, is to interpret it as `lui, $1, str` followed by `lw, $a0,0($1)`. So you write in $1 the address of string str, the  first chars of the array are loaded as an integer in $a0 and you later triy to print string at this (invalid) address. Probably you meant `la $a0, str`.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @AlainMerigot: I think that's a pretty standard pseudo-instruction syntax that would expland to `lui $at, %hi16(str)` / `lw $a0, %lo16(str)($at)`.  That's how `clang -target mips` assembles it this source, according to the relocations you can see with `llvm-objdump -d -r -C` on the `.o`.  It's not a MARS-only extended pseudo-instruction.